# Sorting with filter fuction used in a tab and being able to change a field from any of the tabs

Tags: function, sorting, filter, google-sheets-api

I have created a spreadsheet which uses the filter function to transfer master data based on a type of criteria. On the tab for the criteria I have added two additional fields. I am trying to be able to sort the tab, but I get a blank line inserted above the filtered rows. Ultimately, I would like it to auto sort based on the date feature if possible.

In addition, I am wondering if there is a way I can update the information on the tab with the filter function and have it update the master tab.

Thanks!

Link to the spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/141uweoY2o0xgUo3Uy2Ta-d4w8QG47VSEgodaeWBtucI/edit#gid=2063529495

Comment: Users need to request for access to this spreadsheet.